# nodejs and npm will not work on existing project directory

Tags: installation, filesystems, webserver, symbolic-link, node.js

So, the issue here is that I installed the Node.JS on `c:/app/nodejs`
while my projects are under `c:/app/www`.

I tried to use a dynamic symlink of `www` inside `/nodejs`, but it did not work out.

I also tried to install the Node.JS into `c:/app` **directly** without `nodejs` folder! 
Do I have to install a node in **every** project folder?

I have `WAMP` also run on the `www` folder. Will that cause a problem, or was that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer. Restart the PC. Yes, its that simple.